MacOS Python: "pkg-config exists" returns "1" but "install" says it's there?
During a "pip3 install" sequence, I get this: (this is one of several in a row, for different database alternatives)
Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.

... but ...
    pip3 install mysqlclient
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /Users/mike/.virtualenvs/djangoprod/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.1.1)

Environment is MacOS. It's not "exotic." I've just used the MacOS installer sequence for MySQL, so far –and for quite some time – with success. Until now.
It appears that the installation script fails because it gets a "1" return-code from each of several alternatives, yet "mysqlclient" should have been detected. The line above should have returned zero.

Clearly pkg-config doesn't know about your virtual environment.

I already thought of that, of course. But the virtual-environment IS specified. I will review the list of "related questions" to see if I can find the answer, and if so I will close this question. This IS "MacOS," and I'm not using "brew." (I'm just about to say f&kkit, and install "real Linux" on a virtual machine and do it that way. MacOS is sometimes "just different enough" to be annoying.) Thanks for the input.

Working through other forums, I eventually solved this problem. I could see that the failing package was "mysqlclient". So, I was then pointed to this command: (that I did not previously know about ...)
pkg-config --validate mysqlclient
Which, in its output, said:
Perhaps you should add the directory containing mysqlclient.pc to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
("Gee, thanks ... wish you coulda told me sooner ...")
Using the trusty locate command, I found the proper path, then used export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=... to specify it. Once I did that, the command ran to completion.
This is a project that I haven't worked-on in probably half a year. And I think that it's very likely that the "Requirement already satisfied" message was referring to what I had done "back then."
There definitely was not enough information, in the messages that I had been given, to point me to the actual "right direction." (The "non-zero exit status" message was a red herring.) So, I wanted to take the time to fully follow-up here.
Also: I was briefly side-tracked around the brew command, which is an alternative way of installing things in MacOS. However, I had already installed MySQL using the conventional installer, and that was the mysqlclient.pc file that I used. (I realized the error of my ways and "un-installed" the brew packages since I did not need them. They would have, in fact, created a conflict ...)
